# Scrape Website works with POSTMan fails with C#

Tags: c#, web-scraping, postman

Hi I am working on a **scraping** web app
I need to scrape multiple pages in [[this](https://www.caleprocure.ca.gov)][1](https://www.caleprocure.ca.gov) site
starting with https://www.caleprocure.ca.gov/pages/Events-BS3/event-search.aspx
I created a [POSTMAN collection](https://fil.email/cEZFGoil), which works if I send request twice (first request fails, then click on send again it works)

If I implement same on C# WebAPI Controller, it always fails

```
private async void GetResultsAsync(int maxRetry)
        {
            while (maxRetry >= 0)
            {
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("IF-TargetVerb", "GET"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("IF-TargetContent",
                        "[{\"Lbl\":\"attachmentWrapper\",\"Src\":\"div.InFlightAttachment:first\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[{\"Lbl\":\"attachmentLink\",\"Src\":\".\",\"Data\":\"text:href\",\"Children\":[]}]},{\"Lbl\":\"popupMessageContent\",\"Src\":\"span.InFlightPopup\",\"Data\":\"html\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"pageTitle\",\"Src\":\"div[id*=\'div$ICField85\'] > span\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"if_error_items\",\"Src\":\"span[id=\'RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_INQ_MSG1\']:eq(0)\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"error_items\",\"Src\":\"span[id=\'RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_INQ_MSG1\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"hideSavedSearches\",\"Src\":\"#AUC_PREF_WK_AUC_PREF_SRCH_NAME\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"savedSearchLabelLabel\",\"Src\":\"#AUC_PREF_WK_AUC_PREF_SRCH_NAME_LBL\",\"Data\":\"text for\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"savedSearches\",\"Src\":\"#AUC_PREF_WK_AUC_PREF_SRCH_NAME\",\"Data\":\"name id value\",\"Children\":[{\"Lbl\":\"ptype\",\"Src\":\"option\",\"Data\":\"value text selected disabled\",\"Children\":[]}]},{\"Lbl\":\"eventNameLabel\",\"Src\":\"label[id=\'RESP_INQA_WK_ZZ_AUC_NAME_LBL\']\",\"Data\":\"text for\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"eventNameGrouping\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_ZZ_AUC_NAME\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"eventName\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_ZZ_AUC_NAME\",\"Data\":\"id name value disabled readonly class:tmpclass maxlength\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"eventIdLabel\",\"Src\":\"label[id=\'RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_ID_LBL\']\",\"Data\":\"text for\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"eventIdGrouping\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_ID\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"eventId\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_ID\",\"Data\":\"id name value disabled readonly class:tmpclass maxlength\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"businessUnitLabel\",\"Src\":\"div[id*=\'div$ICField199\'] > span\",\"Data\":\"text for\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"item15\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_BUSINESS_UNIT\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"businessUnit\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_BUSINESS_UNIT\",\"Data\":\"id name value disabled class:tmpclass maxlength\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"businessUnitSelector\",\"Src\":\"a[id^=\'RESP_INQA_WK_BUSINESS_UNIT$prompt\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"businessUnitSubtitle\",\"Src\":\"#BUS_UNIT_TBL_FS_DESCR\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"eventStatusLabel\",\"Src\":\"label[id=\'RESP_INQA_WK_ZZ_EVENT_STATUS_LBL\']\",\"Data\":\"text for\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"item20\",\"Src\":\"select[id=\'RESP_INQA_WK_ZZ_EVENT_STATUS\']\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"eventStatus\",\"Src\":\"select[id=\'RESP_INQA_WK_ZZ_EVENT_STATUS\']\",\"Data\":\"name id value\",\"Children\":[{\"Lbl\":\"ptype\",\"Src\":\"option\",\"Data\":\"value text selected disabled\",\"Children\":[]}]},{\"Lbl\":\"publishedYearLabel\",\"Src\":\"label[id=\'RESP_INQA_WK_YEAR_LBL\']\",\"Data\":\"text for\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"item23\",\"Src\":\"select[id=\'RESP_INQA_WK_YEAR\']\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"publishedYear\",\"Src\":\"select[id=\'RESP_INQA_WK_YEAR\']\",\"Data\":\"name id value\",\"Children\":[{\"Lbl\":\"ptype\",\"Src\":\"option\",\"Data\":\"value text selected disabled\",\"Children\":[]}]},{\"Lbl\":\"datesHider\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_FROM_START_DT\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"startDateFromLabel\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_FROM_START_DT_LBL\",\"Data\":\"text for\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"startDateFromGrouping\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_FROM_START_DT\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"startDateFromHider\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_FROM_START_DT\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"startDateFrom\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_FROM_START_DT\",\"Data\":\"id name value disabled readonly class:tmpclass maxlength\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"startDateToLabel\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_TO_START_DT_LBL\",\"Data\":\"text for\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"startDateToGrouping\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_TO_START_DT\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"startDateToHider\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_TO_START_DT\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"startDateTo\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_TO_START_DT\",\"Data\":\"id name value disabled readonly class:tmpclass maxlength\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"endDateFromLabel\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_FROM_END_DT_LBL\",\"Data\":\"text for\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"endDateFromGrouping\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_FROM_END_DT\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"endDateFromHider\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_FROM_END_DT\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"endDateFrom\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_FROM_END_DT\",\"Data\":\"id name value disabled readonly class:tmpclass maxlength\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"endDateToLabel\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_TO_END_DT_LBL\",\"Data\":\"text for\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"endDateToGrouping\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_TO_END_DT\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"endDateToHider\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_TO_END_DT\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"endDateTo\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_TO_END_DT\",\"Data\":\"id name value disabled readonly class:tmpclass maxlength\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"searchItemDescLabel\",\"Src\":\"label[id=\'RESP_INQA_WK_DESCR254_MIXED_LBL\']\",\"Data\":\"text for\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"searchItemDescGrouping\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_DESCR254_MIXED\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"searchItemDesc\",\"Src\":\"#RESP_INQA_WK_DESCR254_MIXED\",\"Data\":\"id name value disabled readonly class:tmpclass maxlength\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"categoryTH1\",\"Src\":\"span[id=\'RESP_DUMMY2_VW$0#0\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"categoryTH4\",\"Src\":\"span[id=\'RESP_DUMMY2_VW$0#1\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"categoriesRow\",\"Src\":\"tr[id^=\'trRESP_DUMMY2_VW$0_row\']\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"Children\":[{\"Lbl\":\"categoriesArea\",\"Src\":\"input[id^=\'AUC_HDR_CAT_WRK_CATEGORY_CD\']\",\"Data\":\"id name value disabled class:tmpclass maxlength\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"categoriesAreaLookup\",\"Src\":\"a[id^=\'AUC_HDR_CAT_WRK_CATEGORY_CD$prompt\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"descr\",\"Src\":\"span[id^=\'AUC_HDR_CAT_WRK_DESCR60$\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"categoryDeleteButton\",\"Src\":\"a[id^=\'RESP_DUMMY2_VW$delete$\']\",\"Data\":\"id name disabled\",\"Children\":[]}]},{\"Lbl\":\"subCategoriesTH1\",\"Src\":\"span[id=\'RESP_DUMMY2_VW$0#0\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"item49\",\"Src\":\"input[type=hidden][id^=\'RESP_DUMMY2_VW$selmh$\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"subCategoryTH5\",\"Src\":\"span[id=\'RESP_DUMMY2_VW$0#1\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"AddCategoryAreaButton\",\"Src\":\"[id^=\'RESP_DUMMY2_VW$new$\']:last\",\"Data\":\"id name disabled role tabindex\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"ServiceTitle\",\"Src\":\"div[id*=\'ZZ_RESP_DMY1_VWGP$0\'] td[class=\'PSLEVEL1GRIDLABEL\']:first\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"serviceTH1\",\"Src\":\"span[id=\'ZZ_RESP_DMY1_VW$0#0\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"serviceTH4\",\"Src\":\"span[id=\'ZZ_RESP_DMY1_VW$0#1\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"serviceRow\",\"Src\":\"tr[id^=\'trZZ_RESP_DMY1_VW$0_row\']\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"Children\":[{\"Lbl\":\"serviceArea\",\"Src\":\"input[id^=\'ZZ_PO_DOC_WRK_ZZ_SRVC_AREA_ID$\']\",\"Data\":\"id name value disabled class:tmpclass maxlength\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"serviceAreaLookup\",\"Src\":\"a[id^=\'ZZ_PO_DOC_WRK_ZZ_SRVC_AREA_ID$prompt$\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"county\",\"Src\":\"span[id^=\'ZZ_SA_VW_COUNTY$\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"deleteButton\",\"Src\":\"a[id^=\'ZZ_RESP_DMY1_VW$delete$\']\",\"Data\":\"id name disabled\",\"Children\":[]}]},{\"Lbl\":\"subServiceTH5\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'ZZ_RESP_DMY1_VW$0#1\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"NewServiceButton\",\"Src\":\"[id^=\'ZZ_RESP_DMY1_VW$new$\']:last\",\"Data\":\"id name disabled role tabindex\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"LicenseClassifactionTitle\",\"Src\":\"div[id*=\'ZZ_RESP_DMY2_VWGP$0\'] td[class=\'PSLEVEL1GRIDLABEL\']:first\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"licenseTH1\",\"Src\":\"span[id=\'ZZ_RESP_DMY2_VW$0#0\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"licenseTH4\",\"Src\":\"span[id=\'ZZ_RESP_DMY2_VW$0#1\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"licenseRow\",\"Src\":\"tr[id^=\'trZZ_RESP_DMY2_VW$0_row\']\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"Children\":[{\"Lbl\":\"licenseArea\",\"Src\":\"input[id^=\'ZZ_PO_DOC_WRK_ZZ_LICENSE_CLASS\']\",\"Data\":\"id name value disabled class:tmpclass maxlength\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"licenseAreaLookup\",\"Src\":\"a[id^=\'ZZ_PO_DOC_WRK_ZZ_LICENSE_CLASS$prompt$\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"county\",\"Src\":\"span[id^=\'ZZ_CLS_CD_VW_DESCR254\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"licenseDeleteButton\",\"Src\":\"a[id^=\'ZZ_RESP_DMY2_VW$delete$\']\",\"Data\":\"id name disabled\",\"Children\":[]}]},{\"Lbl\":\"subLicenseTH1\",\"Src\":\"span[id=\'ZZ_RESP_DMY2_VW$0#0\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"subLicenseTH5\",\"Src\":\"span[id=\'ZZ_RESP_DMY2_VW$0#1\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"AddLicenseButton\",\"Src\":\"[id^=\'ZZ_RESP_DMY2_VW$new\']:last\",\"Data\":\"id name disabled role tabindex\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"item65\",\"Src\":\"#AUC_PREF_WK_AUC_PREF_CLEAR_PB\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"SaveCriteria\",\"Src\":\"a[id=\'AUC_PREF_WK_AUC_PREF_ADD_PB\']\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[{\"Lbl\":\"SaveCriteriaButton\",\"Src\":\".\",\"Data\":\"id name disabled\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"SaveCriteriaText\",\"Src\":\".\",\"Data\":\"text value:data-value\",\"Children\":[]}]},{\"Lbl\":\"AdvancedSearch\",\"Src\":\"a[id=\'RESP_INQA_WK_AUC_SRCH_ADVBSC_PB\']\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[{\"Lbl\":\"AdvancedSearchButton\",\"Src\":\".\",\"Data\":\"id name disabled\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"AdvancedSearchText\",\"Src\":\".\",\"Data\":\"text value:data-value\",\"Children\":[]}]},{\"Lbl\":\"Search\",\"Src\":\"input[id=\'RESP_INQA_WK_INQ_AUC_GO_PB\']\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[{\"Lbl\":\"SearchButton\",\"Src\":\".\",\"Data\":\"id name disabled\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"SearchText\",\"Src\":\".\",\"Data\":\"value:text\",\"Children\":[]}]},{\"Lbl\":\"eventtable\",\"Src\":\"table[id*=\'$scroll$0\']\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"pagergrPager\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$hmodal$0\']\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"firstPagegrPager\",\"Src\":\"a[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$htop$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"prevPagegrPager\",\"Src\":\"a[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$hup$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"pagePosgrPager\",\"Src\":\"div[id*=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GRGP\'] span[class=PSGRIDCOUNTER]\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"viewAllgrPager\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$hviewall$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name text\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"downloadSearchgrPager\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$hexcel$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"nextPagegrPager\",\"Src\":\"a[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$hdown$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"lastPagegrPager\",\"Src\":\"a[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$hend$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"pagervwPager\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW$hmodal$0\']\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"firstPagevwPager\",\"Src\":\"a[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW$htop$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"prevPagevwPager\",\"Src\":\"a[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW$hup$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"pagePosvwPager\",\"Src\":\"div[id*=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VWGP\'] span[class=PSGRIDCOUNTER]\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"viewAllvwPager\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW$hviewall$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name text\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"downloadSearchvwPager\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW$hexcel$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"nextPagevwPager\",\"Src\":\"a[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW$hdown$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"lastPagevwPager\",\"Src\":\"a[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW$hend$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"tbl\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'l0RESP_INQA_HD_VW$0\'],[id=\'l0RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id\",\"Children\":[{\"Lbl\":\"tblHeadTr\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'l1RESP_INQA_HD_VW$0\'],[id=\'l1RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id\",\"Children\":[{\"Lbl\":\"thEventId\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'thRESP_INQA_HD_VW$0#2\'],[id=\'thRESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$0#2\']\",\"Data\":\"id:data-key\",\"Children\":[{\"Lbl\":\"thSpan\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW$0#2\'],[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$0#2\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"thup\",\"Src\":\"img[src*=\'UP\']\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"thdn\",\"Src\":\"img[src*=\'DN\']\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]}]},{\"Lbl\":\"thEventName\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'thRESP_INQA_HD_VW$0#3\'],[id=\'thRESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$0#3\']\",\"Data\":\"id:data-key\",\"Children\":[{\"Lbl\":\"thSpan\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW$0#3\'],[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$0#3\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"thup\",\"Src\":\"img[src*=\'UP\']\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"thdn\",\"Src\":\"img[src*=\'DN\']\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]}]},{\"Lbl\":\"thDepName\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'thRESP_INQA_HD_VW$0#1\'],[id=\'thRESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$0#1\']\",\"Data\":\"id:data-key\",\"Children\":[{\"Lbl\":\"thSpan\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW$0#1\'],[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$0#1\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"thup\",\"Src\":\"img[src*=\'UP\']\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"thdn\",\"Src\":\"img[src*=\'DN\']\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]}]},{\"Lbl\":\"thPubDate\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'thRESP_INQA_HD_VW$0#6\'],[id=\'thRESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$0#6\']\",\"Data\":\"id:data-key\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[{\"Lbl\":\"thSpan\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW$0#6\'],[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$0#6\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"thup\",\"Src\":\"img[src*=\'UP\']\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"thdn\",\"Src\":\"img[src*=\'DN\']\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]}]},{\"Lbl\":\"thEndDate\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'thRESP_INQA_HD_VW$0#7\'],[id=\'thRESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$0#7\']\",\"Data\":\"id:data-key\",\"Children\":[{\"Lbl\":\"thSpan\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW$0#7\'],[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$0#7\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"thup\",\"Src\":\"img[src*=\'UP\']\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"thdn\",\"Src\":\"img[src*=\'DN\']\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]}]},{\"Lbl\":\"thStatus\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'thRESP_INQA_HD_VW$0#8\'],[id=\'thRESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$0#8\']\",\"Data\":\"id:data-key\",\"Children\":[{\"Lbl\":\"thSpan\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW$0#8\'],[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$0#8\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"thup\",\"Src\":\"img[src*=\'UP\']\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"thdn\",\"Src\":\"img[src*=\'DN\']\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]}]}]},{\"Lbl\":\"tblBodyTr\",\"Src\":\"tr[id^=\'trRESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$0_row\'],tr[id^=\'trRESP_INQA_HD_VW$0_row\']\",\"Children\":[{\"Lbl\":\"tdEventId\",\"Src\":\"a[id^=\'AUC_ID_COL$\'],a[id^=\'AUC_ID_BUS_UNIT$\']\",\"Data\":\"text id name\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"tdEventName\",\"Src\":\"[id^=\'RESP_INQA1_WK_ZZ_AUC_NAME$\'],[id^=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_ZZ_AUC_NAME$\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"tdDepName\",\"Src\":\"[id^=\'BUS_UNIT_TBL_FS_DESCR$\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"tdPubDate\",\"Src\":\"[id^=\'AUC_DTTM_FINISH_FR$\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"tdEndDate\",\"Src\":\"[id^=\'RESP_INQA1_WK_AUC_DTTM_FINISH$\'],[id^=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_AUC_DTTM_FINISH$\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"tdStatus\",\"Src\":\"[id^=\'ZZ_DERIVED_DESCR\']\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]}]}]},{\"Lbl\":\"pagergrPager\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$hmodal$0\']\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"firstPagegrPager\",\"Src\":\"a[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$htop$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"prevPagegrPager\",\"Src\":\"a[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$hup$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"pagePosgrPager\",\"Src\":\"div[id*=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GRGP\'] span[class=PSGRIDCOUNTER]\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"viewAllgrPager\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$hviewall$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name text\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"downloadSearchgrPager\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$hexcel$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"nextPagegrPager\",\"Src\":\"a[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$hdown$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"lastPagegrPager\",\"Src\":\"a[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW_GR$hend$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"pagervwPager\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW$hmodal$0\']\",\"Data\":\"null\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"firstPagevwPager\",\"Src\":\"a[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW$htop$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"prevPagevwPager\",\"Src\":\"a[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW$hup$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"pagePosvwPager\",\"Src\":\"div[id*=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VWGP\'] span[class=PSGRIDCOUNTER]\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"viewAllvwPager\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW$hviewall$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name text\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"downloadSearchvwPager\",\"Src\":\"[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW$hexcel$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"nextPagevwPager\",\"Src\":\"a[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW$hdown$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"lastPagevwPager\",\"Src\":\"a[id=\'RESP_INQA_HD_VW$hend$0\']\",\"Data\":\"id name\",\"HWA\":\".\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"doPortalUrlText\",\"Src\":\"script:contains(\'DoPortalUrl\')\",\"Data\":\"text\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Lbl\":\"hiddenInput\",\"Src\":\"input[type=hidden]\",\"Data\":\"id name value\",\"Children\":[]}]"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("IF-Template", "/pages/Events-BS3/event-search.aspx"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("IF-IgnoreContent", string.Empty),
                });

                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referer",
                    "https://www.caleprocure.ca.gov/pages/Events-BS3/event-search.aspx");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Origin", "https://www.caleprocure.ca.gov");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "www.caleprocure.ca.gov");

                var mainResponse = await client.PostAsync(_baseUrl, content);
                var mainPageContents = await mainResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if (mainResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    continue;
                var jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(mainPageContents);
                var captureResults = (JObject) jsonResponse["CaptureResults"];
                JArray elements = new JArray();
                var tblBodyTr = (JArray) captureResults["tbl"]["Children"]["tblBodyTr"];
                foreach (var tr in tblBodyTr)
                {
                    var element = (JObject) tr["Children"]["tdEventId"][0]["Properties"];
                    elements.Add(element);
                }

                maxRetry--;
            }
        }
```

Also what is the best ways to simulate click of each result in [this page](https://www.caleprocure.ca.gov/pages/Events-BS3/event-search.aspx) scrape data from that details page?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

When it fails it returns 278 status code with the following JSON response

```
{"IFLocation":"/--IF/PD1/InFlightViewer1/68/DisplayLang=ENG/NLX3/FI--/psc/psfpd1/SUPPLIER/ERP/c/AUC_MANAGE_BIDS.AUC_RESP_INQ_AUC.GBL?bCDC=y&"}
```

When it is successful, it returns 200 status code with a large JSON response as below (collapsed on main nodes to fit in the picture)
[image]

Comment: What does "Fails" mean? Nothing back, exception, wrong data, etc?

Comment: Expected status code 200 but it get 278 and expect a large JSON response, but I get {"IFLocation":"/--IF/PD1/InFlightViewer1/68/DisplayLang=ENG/NLX3/FI--/psc/psfpd1/SUPPLIER/ERP/c/AUC_MANAGE_BIDS.AUC_RESP_INQ_AUC.GBL?bCDC=y&"}

Comment: @HaBo 278 isn't an HTTP status code. Use a debugging proxy to see what's actually going on, both with POSTMAN and your own code. How does the HTTP request sent from your code differ from POSTMAN? Are you missing some cookies? A header? Some hidden field value?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos nothing is missing. I attached my POSTMAN collection as well for reference. And interestingly POSTMAN also get 278 status for first attempt, then if I make another attempt then I get 200. But with C# it is always getting 278 even if I do retry for 30 times.

Comment: @HaBo it's also possible that the server detects that you haven't logged in and tries to redirect you to another page. Googling shows that 278 is used sometimes as a dummy code to redirect "AJAX" requests.

Comment: @HaBo if nothing is missing, there's no difference in the responses either and you have no problem. Quite clearly, something is very different. Use Fiddler, don't *assume*

Comment: @Habo for example [this article](https://odino.org/frontend-web-development-is-not-as-fun-as-it-should-be/) describes how 278 is used to abuse HTTP to same mobile developers a redirection. Instead of redirecting you to the proper URL, the server sends a dummy 278 to the mobile client or SPA with a URL to display and the payload that the *new* URL would return. That `IFLocation` looks a lot like a URL